# TimePicker with 15 minutes interval in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, timepicker, numberpicker

I need to set 15 minutes interval in Time Picker. I have done for iOS. But in Android it is not working.

For iOS I used following code and it is working:

```
public class CustomTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
    {             base.OnElementChanged(e);             var view = (TimePicker)Element; 
        if (view != null)
        {                 var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
            timePicker.MinuteInterval = 15;             }
    }
}
```

For Andoroid I am trying with following code:

```
public class CustomTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    Context _context;

    public CustomTimePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        TimePickerDialogIntervals timePickerDlg = new TimePickerDialogIntervals(this.Context, new EventHandler<TimePickerDialogIntervals.TimeSetEventArgs>(UpdateDuration),
            Element.Time.Hours, Element.Time.Minutes, true);

        var control = new EditText(this.Context);
        control.Focusable = false;
        control.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
        control.Clickable = false;
        control.Click += (sender, ea) => timePickerDlg.Show();
        control.Text = Element.Time.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + Element.Time.Minutes.ToString("00");

        SetNativeControl(control);
    }

    void UpdateDuration(object sender, Android.App.TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs e)
    {
        Element.Time = new TimeSpan(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute, 0);
        Control.Text = Element.Time.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + Element.Time.Minutes.ToString("00");
    }
}

public class TimePickerDialogIntervals : TimePickerDialog
{
    public const int TimePickerInterval = 15;
    private bool _ignoreEvent = false;

    public TimePickerDialogIntervals(Context context, EventHandler<TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs> callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, bool is24HourView)
        : base(context, (sender, e) => {
            callBack(sender, new TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute * TimePickerInterval));
        }, hourOfDay, minute / TimePickerInterval, is24HourView)
    {
    }

    protected TimePickerDialogIntervals(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public override void SetView(Android.Views.View view)
    {
        SetupMinutePicker(view);
        base.SetView(view);
    }

    void SetupMinutePicker(Android.Views.View view)
    {
        var numberPicker =  FindMinuteNumberPicker(view as ViewGroup);
        if (numberPicker != null)
        {
            numberPicker.MinValue = 0;
            numberPicker.MaxValue = 3;
            numberPicker.SetDisplayedValues(new String[] { "00", "15", "30", "45" });
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative).Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;
        this.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    private NumberPicker FindMinuteNumberPicker(ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);
            var numberPicker = child as NumberPicker;
            if (numberPicker != null)
            {
                if (numberPicker.MaxValue == 59)
                {
                    return numberPicker;
                }
            }

            var childViewGroup = child as ViewGroup;
            if (childViewGroup != null)
            {
                var childResult = FindMinuteNumberPicker(childViewGroup);
                if (childResult != null)
                    return childResult;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

But Android code is not working. I think the issue is with the number picker in SetupMinutePicker method. I am getting null in number picker.
Please let me know how I can fix this number picker issue or is there any alternate solution to set 15 minutes interval in time picker.

Comment: Hi, I have checked this in my local site, it seems not works in Android now. I will contiune to find the solution, if good news will update here later.

Comment: Thanks @JuniorJiang-MSFT . Please let me know if you get the solution for android.

Comment: I have found a workaround for this problem and update it in answer, you can have a look at that when you have time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109944/xamarin-forms-different-time-is-showing-on-the-ui-after-clock-pop-is-closed-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a **workaround** for Android. The previous override `SetView(...)` method can not get the `NumberPicker` now, here we can change the minutes interval in override `OnTimeChanged` method as follow:

```
public override void OnTimeChanged(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
{
    if (_ignoreEvent) return;

    if (minute % TimePickerInterval != 0)
    {
        int minuteFloor = minute - (minute % TimePickerInterval);
        minute = minuteFloor + (minute == minuteFloor + 1 ? TimePickerInterval : 0);
        if (minute == 60)
            minute = 0;
        _ignoreEvent = true;
        view.CurrentMinute = (Java.Lang.Integer)minute;
        _ignoreEvent = false;
    }
}
```

The full android renderer code is as follow:

```
public class CustomTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        TimePickerDialogIntervals timePickerDlg = new TimePickerDialogIntervals(this.Context, new EventHandler<TimePickerDialogIntervals.TimeSetEventArgs>(UpdateDuration),
            Element.Time.Hours, Element.Time.Minutes, true);

        var control = new EditText(this.Context);
        control.Focusable = false;
        control.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
        control.Clickable = false;
        control.Click += (sender, ea) => timePickerDlg.Show();
        control.Text = Element.Time.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + Element.Time.Minutes.ToString("00");

        SetNativeControl(control);
    }

    void UpdateDuration(object sender, Android.App.TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs e)
    {
        Element.Time = new TimeSpan(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute, 0);
        Control.Text = Element.Time.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + Element.Time.Minutes.ToString("00");
    }
}

public class TimePickerDialogIntervals : TimePickerDialog
{
    public const int TimePickerInterval = 15;
    private bool _ignoreEvent = false;

    public TimePickerDialogIntervals(Context context, EventHandler<TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs> callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, bool is24HourView)
        : base(context, (sender, e) => {
            callBack(sender, new TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute * TimePickerInterval));
        }, hourOfDay, minute / TimePickerInterval, is24HourView)
    {
    }

    public override void OnTimeChanged(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        base.OnTimeChanged(view, hourOfDay, minute);
        
        if (_ignoreEvent) return;

        if (minute % TimePickerInterval != 0)
        {
            int minuteFloor = minute - (minute % TimePickerInterval);
            minute = minuteFloor + (minute == minuteFloor + 1 ? TimePickerInterval : 0);
            if (minute == 60)
                minute = 0;
            _ignoreEvent = true;
            view.CurrentMinute = (Java.Lang.Integer)minute;
            _ignoreEvent = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109944/xamarin-forms-different-time-is-showing-on-the-ui-after-clock-pop-is-closed-in

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution from Junior Jiang **did not work anymore in Xamarin.Forms 5.0**. The reason for this is that the base renderer always calls its own TimePickerDialog. Fortunately you can override the necessary method.

I also changed the behaviour that the minutes jump to the next interval that is nearest to the current position. I think this is a liitle more snappy than pulling completely to the next interval. Also there was a minor calculation error on some specific values for the minute which caused a flickering of the pointer.

```
public class IntervalTimePickerRenderer : TimePickerRenderer
{
    private Context _context;

    public IntervalTimePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override TimePickerDialog CreateTimePickerDialog(int hours, int minutes)
    {
        return new TimePickerDialogIntervals(
            Context,
            UpdateDuration,
            hours,
            minutes,
            DateFormat.Is24HourFormat(_context));
    }

    void UpdateDuration(object sender, TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs e)
    {
        Element.Time = new TimeSpan(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute, 0);
        Control.Text = Element.Time.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + Element.Time.Minutes.ToString("00");

        Element.Unfocus();
    }
}

public class TimePickerDialogIntervals : TimePickerDialog
{
    public const int TimePickerInterval = 15;
    private bool _ignoreEvent = false;

    public TimePickerDialogIntervals(
        Context context,
        EventHandler<TimeSetEventArgs> callBack,
        int hourOfDay,
        int minute,
        bool is24HourView)
        : base(context,
              (sender, e) =>
              {
                  callBack(sender, new TimePickerDialog.TimeSetEventArgs(e.HourOfDay, e.Minute));
              },
              hourOfDay,
              minute,
              is24HourView)
    {
    }

    public override void OnTimeChanged(Android.Widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        base.OnTimeChanged(view, hourOfDay, minute);

        if (_ignoreEvent) return;

        if (minute % TimePickerInterval != 0)
        {
            float minuteFactor = (float)minute / TimePickerInterval;
            int intervalFactor = (int)Math.Round(minuteFactor, 0);

            minute = intervalFactor * TimePickerInterval;
            
            if (minute == 60)
            {
                minute = 0;
            }

            _ignoreEvent = true;
            view.Minute = minute;
            _ignoreEvent = false;
        }
    }
}
```